# jQuery animating width of variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm having trouble getting smooth animation on a div width that I've set as a variable. It's supposed to animate similar to a progress bar. I have a demo on [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srQVv/). How can I get a smooth animation? Thank you!

HTML:

```
<div id="pb"><div></div></div>

<a href="#" class="test" data-value="25%">25</a>
<a href="#" class="test" data-value="50%">50</a>
<a href="#" class="test" data-value="75%">75</a>    
<a href="#" class="test" data-value="100%">100</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $( "#pb div" ).width("50%");

    $('.test').click( function () {
         var value = parseInt($(this).attr('data-value'));
        var test = $( "#pb div" ).css({width: (value) + '%'});

        $('#pb div').animate({
            width: test,
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/srQVv/2/)***

You were already there :)

Just use your value in the animation instead of directly setting the width via the css property like this:

```
$('#pb div').animate({
        width: value+"%",
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your line **var test = ...** is already changing the css width.
Instead just use the animate function as below:

```
$(function () {
    $( "#pb div" ).width("50%");

    $('.test').click( function () {
        var value = parseInt($(this).attr('data-value'));
        test = $( "#pb div" ).animate({width: (value) + '%'});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the same width with `.css` and with `.animate`, so it won't have any frames to animate:

```
$(function () {
    $("#pb div").width("50%");

    $('.test').click(function() {
        $('#pb div').stop().animate({
            width: $(this).data('value')
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/srQVv/1/**

Comment: Thank you for your help; it works perfectly. May I ask what the benefit of adding `.stop()` and `.data()` is in comparison to what @TravisJ suggested?